# jQuery mousemove - applying CSS filter based on mouse position

Tags: jquery, css, filter, mousemove

I'm trying to set up a very simple mousemove event, which applies **filter: (XXdeg)** CSS to my background div based on mouse position. I've done this successfully in the past with background-color but it doesn't seem to be working for the filter property.

Here's what I have:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    var $width = ($(document).width())/255;
    var $height = ($(document).height())/255;
    var $pageX = parseInt(e.pageX / $width,10);
    var $pageY = parseInt(e.pageY / $height,10);
    $(".bg").css("filter", "hue-rotate(" + (255 - $pageX) + ")");
});
```

Would very much appreciate if someone could point out where I might be going wrong with this. Page with this code applied is here: http://www.joe-goddard.com

Thanks!

Comment: You're aware that you've implemented 2 fb pixels?

Comment: As a matter of fact, I just realized that you are trying to achieve a value from 0 to 255, but the maximum value for a hue filter is 360. Just keep that in mind :v

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried that code, the only thing you're missing is the "deg" unit after the filter value.

```
var $document = $(document);

$document.mousemove(function(e) {
    var width = $document.width() / 255;
    var pageX = e.pageX / width;
    var value = 255 - pageX;

    $(".bg").css("filter", "hue-rotate(" + value + "deg)");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify **what unit** will be 255, in this case, `deg` (degree).

```
 $(".bg").css("filter", "hue-rotate(" + (255 - $pageX) + "deg)");
```

[Working codepen example](http://codepen.io/robertspier/pen/vypMBp?editors=1111)